# Netlogo calculate all turtles of a type that are touching

Tags: while-loop, netlogo

In Netlogo, I have a grid of turtles all touching, and I want to count the number of green turtles  (MHC = 3 in code below) that form each cluster of green turtles (amid the other colours). Perhaps I am going about it all wrong, but it seems very very hard.

I have tried while loops designed to start with a single green cell (unconnected to any previous green cluster) and assign a number to its turtles-own variable `block`. Then each green neighbor `in-radius 1` receives the same number, and so on and so on, until each touching green cell receives the same number. Then the next cluster will receive a new number and start over.
However, unless it's just a question of bad bracketing, it really doesn't seem to work. Here is the functional code (which just creates the grid of colour changing turtles):

```
turtles-own[MHC block]

globals[prWound]

to set-up
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [sprout 1 [set color magenta]]
  ask turtles [set MHC 2]
  set prWound 0.0001
end

to rules
  ask turtles with [MHC = 0][set color red]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 1][set color green]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 2][set color magenta]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 3][set color blue]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 4][set color orange]

ask turtles [if random 100 < 1 [set MHC (random 5)] ;vary MHC betwen 0-4,
    set block 0
    if random-float 1 < prWound [ask turtles in-radius 4 [die] die] 
    if any? patches in-radius 1 with [not any? turtles-here] and random 100 < 50 [if random 100 < 2.5 
[set MHC (random 5)] hatch 1 [move-to one-of patches in-radius 1 with [not any? turtles-here]
  ]
  tick
end

to go
  rules
end
```

Here is the part where I try to add `block` values that I cannot get to work (added just before the tick):

```
  ask turtles with [MHC = 1][
    if block = 0 [set block (max([block] of turtles) + 1) ]
    while [any? [turtles with [MHC = 1 and block = 0] in-radius 1] of turtles with [block = [block] of myself]]
[if any? [turtles with [MHC = 1 and block = 0] in-radius 1] of turtles with [block = [block] of myself]
[set block ([block] of myself)]]
  ]
```

I think the in-radius might be at least one of the problems - I am not sure it can be used this way.

Comment: Note that there is a problem with brackets in your example, after the command block that follows `hatch 1`.

Comment: Also, for future questions, please specify what is the unexpected behaviour you are seeing (i.e. instead of just "it doesn't work") - this will help you get helped.

Comment: Right, will do. I have added the error message below for any future readers:
ANY? expected input to be an agentset but got the list [(agentset, 0 turtles)] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: simpler approach

I leave my initial reply below unchanged, however see that a much simpler approach can be taken:

```
to count-blocks
  set block-now 0
  
  ask turtles [set block 0]
  
  while [any? turtles with [condition]] [
   set block-now block-now + 1
   
   ask one-of turtles with [condition] [
     join-and-search 
    ]
  ]
end


to join-and-search
  set block block-now
  
  if any? (turtles-on neighbors) with [condition] [
   ask (turtles-on neighbors) with [condition] [
      join-and-search
    ]
  ]
end


to-report condition
  ifelse (color = green and block = 0)
   [report TRUE]
   [report FALSE]
end
```

Note that, although `while` is used only once in this case, `to join-and-search` in actual fact creates a loop by calling itself, with the recursive call being performed only `if any? (turtles on neighbor) with [condition]` exist; which makes the `candidate?` passage (i.e. becoming a candidate, recruiting candidates, stop being a candidate) not required here.

I think that just a warning is due in this case: I don't know if it is best practice to let a procedure call itself. On the one hand, it sounds like something worth flagging; on the other hand, it seems to me that this `join-and-search` could not be any more problematic than any other loop built with a weird condition.

### Initial reply

While trying to solve this, I myself discovered something that I did not consider about `in-radius`, and surely there lies part of the problem.

Before disclosing that, however, let me say that I am not sure if this `in-radius`-thing is everything that was wrong with your attempt: by the time I found out about it, I had already taken my approach to the problem.

In general, however, one piece of advice: keep your code as tidy and as readable as possible (including indentation) - it becomes a lot easier to spot where a problem lies.

That said, the main elements of my approach:

- Two `while` loops: the first one checks whether there are any eligible turtles in the whole simulation that will initiate a new `block`; the second one (nested within the first one) checks whether there are any turtles left to be allocated to the current `block` being evaluated.
- A `candidate?` `turtles-own` variable, which constitutes the condition for the second `while` loop. When being allocated to a block, each turtle also performs a search of its neighbours. If there are any turtles that should be added to the current block, then these get `candidate? = TRUE` and the inner loop starts again.
- Also, I've split the relatively few commands in many procedures with relevant names. This makes both the code more readable but also more scalable: when you're going to expand on the model's variables, agentsets, conditions etc it will be easier to add line of codes to allocated sections and check whether a particular section is working on its own.
- `to-report condition` and the global variable `block-now` exist mainly for readability.
- As of now, this code re-counts blocks at every `go` (and blocks may change number between one iteration of `go` and the other). It will surely be possible to adapt the approach to the case in which you want to keep blocks' numbers across `go` iterations.

```
globals [
  prWound
  block-now
]

turtles-own [
 MHC
 block
 candidate?
]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  ask patches [sprout 1 [set color magenta]]
  ask turtles [set MHC 2]
  set prWound 0.0001
end


to go
  rules
  count-blocks
  tick
end


to rules
  ask turtles with [MHC = 0][set color red]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 1][set color green]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 2][set color magenta]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 3][set color blue]
  ask turtles with [MHC = 4][set color orange]

ask turtles [
    if random 100 < 1 [set MHC (random 5)] 
    set block 0
    if random-float 1 < prWound [ask turtles in-radius 4 [die] die]
    if any? patches in-radius 1 with [not any? turtles-here] and random 100 < 50 [
     if random 100 < 2.5 [
       set MHC random 5
      ]
      hatch 1 [move-to one-of patches in-radius 1 with [not any? turtles-here]]
    ]
  ]
end


to count-blocks
  set block-now 0
  
  ask turtles [
   set block 0
  ]
  
  while [any? turtles with [condition]] [start-count-round]
  
end


to start-count-round
  
  set block-now (block-now + 1)
  
  ask turtles [
   set candidate? FALSE
  ]
  
  ask one-of turtles with [condition] [set candidate? TRUE]
  
  while [any? turtles with [candidate?]] [
    ask turtles with [candidate?] [
     join
     search
     conclude 
    ]
  ]
end


to join
  set block block-now
end


to search
  let target (turtles-on neighbors) with [condition and not candidate?]
  ask target [set candidate? TRUE]
end


to conclude
  set candidate? FALSE
end


to-report condition
  ifelse (color = green and block = 0)
   [report TRUE]
   [report FALSE]
end
```

### Before

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk8yL.png)

### After

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6GoZ.png)

### What about `in-radius`?

While it may seem intuitive that a turtle looking for `turtles in-radius 1` will find the turtles standing on any of the immediate neighboring patches, that is not the case: the input number for `in-radius` [is in fact a distance](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-radius) - i.e. not the number of patches that need to be crossed.

In terms of distance, turtles standing on horizontally- or vertically-neighboring patches will be at a distance of 1. Instead, turtles standing on diagonally-neighboring patches will be at a distance of 1.4:

```
observer> clear-all
observer> ask patch 0 0 [sprout 1]
observer> ask patch 0 1 [sprout 1]
observer> ask patch 1 1 [sprout 1]
observer> ask turtle 0 [show distance turtle 1]
(turtle 0): 1
observer> ask turtle 0 [show distance turtle 2]
(turtle 0): 1.4142135623730951
```

This is the reason why not even my approach was working until I replaced `let target turtles in-radius 1 with [condition and not candidate?]` with `let target (turtles-on neighbors) with [condition and not candidate?]`.

Note that you use `in-radius` twice in the first chunk of code that you shared. While in one case that is just `patches in-radius 1`, which you can replace with `neighbors`, in another instance it is `turtles in-radius 4`. You might want to consider the effect of that distance thing in the latter case.

### A final note on the code

Just to make sure: are you sure that the order of things in `to rules` is what you want? For how things are now, turtles change their `MHC` value but only change colour in the subsequent round of `go` (but, by that time, they will have changed `MHC` again).

Comment: That is also a good point about the colour change, I will change that as well, though my main output is spreadsheets of data